# PowerShell Azure function - use internal function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I had a powershell script, which I am not trying to convert to an Azure Function.  The script is quite simple, but uses function definitions - something like this:

```
function InternalFunction {
    # Do some processing
    ...
}

$someData = ...
$someOtherData = 
...
# now call internal function
InternalFunction $someData
...
InternalFunction $someOtherData
```

Now I put this code in `run.ps1` in my Azure function code - and it fails complaining that `InternalFunction` is not a known cmdlet.  Specifically, I get this in the log:

> The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'InternalFunction'...

So, is there a way to do it using "internal" functions or do I need to rewrite everything to be one function?

Comment: Don't use `$input` as self-defined variable because it is an automatic variable in PowerShell

Comment: @Theo yes, I know, thanks - I only used it for demonstration purpose.  Real code has different variable names. I updated the question to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: In general, this definitely works. However, there are some opportunities to get this wrong, starting from a simple typo. If you simplify and post your actual code, this will help.

Comment: Please update the question to show us a more realistic code example. Now it seems you are defining a function that takes no parameters, but yet you call it using one.. This means the function has a different signature then what you do in calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off defining your functions inside a module and uploading the module with your code.

You can add your own modules by creating a `Modules` folder at the root of your functionapps directory, this is then appended to your `$PSModulePath` when the host starts up so that your module is discoverable.

You can find the docs on the folder structure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#folder-structure)